# element div (token) in position absolute on image in position relative. on resize image update position token

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

my problem is as follows :

I have an image on which I add elements that serve as a token. Like on googleMap.
To adapt to all the sizes of screen I resize the image according to the size of screen.
The size of the image is redefined but I can not position the tokens according to their top and left position depending on the size of the image to which the tokens have been added and the new size of the image .

thank you

Comment: Provide code example please.